# Split column into multiple rows and keeping other columns as well?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need a mysql query that will split the item_code field into multiple rows.

from  this

```
order_no | date       | time    | store_id | authorised_by | item_code
1        | 22/10/2014 | 11:58PM | 3674     | AAA           | 773,724,638,698,782
2        | 23/10/2014 | 08:13AM | 219      | BBB           | 638,625,891
```

to this

```
order_no | date       | time    | store_id | authorised_by | item_code
1        | 22/10/2014 | 11:58PM | 3674     | AAA           | 773,724,638,698,782
         |            |         | 3674     |               | 724
         |            |         | 3674     |               | 638
         |            |         | 3674     |               | 698
         |            |         | 3674     |               | 782
2        | 23/10/2014 | 08:13AM | 219      | BBB           | 638,625,891
         |            |         | 219      |               | 638
         |            |         | 219      |               | 625
         |            |         | 219      |               | 891
```

Comment: This is really difficult to do in MySQL. Do it in PHP with `explode()`. It would be best if you normalized your database so you didn't have comma-separated lists in tables.

Comment: Why isn't there a row for `item_code = 773` in your sample output?

Comment: @Barmar 773 also needs to be in there, sorry that was a typo mistke.

Comment: Why are you not repeating all the columns for the different rows?  This makes the table "un-relational".  For instance, the additional rows have no connection to `order_no`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can do that but it would require manual labour to import the finished result into an inventory system.